# Need to know which div is showing on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a swipe effect but move position of upper div by calculating the x, y coordinates and then move the wrapper(upper most div) with screen width, so it looks like swipe effect.

Now my problem is I dont know which in the next div showing on the screen, I need to manipulate on that, is there any method I can get the current div id which is showing on the DIV.

Below is my JS Code

```
    (function() {
   var swipey = {
      slideContainer: null, //<ul> element object that holds the image slides
      wrapper: null, //meant for masking/clipping
      slides: null, //array of all slides i.e <li> elements
      distanceX: 0, //distance moved in X direction i.e left or right
      startX: 0, //registers the initial touch co-ordinate
      preferredWidth: 0, //dynamic variable to set width
      preferredHeight: 0, //dynamic variable to set height
      direction: "", //direction of movement
      timer: null, //timer that set starts when touch starts
      timerCounter: 0, //counter variable for timer
      hasSwipeStarted: false, //boolen to chk whether touch has started
      maxDistance: 0, //maximum distance in X direction that slide container can move
      currentDistance: 0, //current distance moved by slide container through translate

      //detect touch and then automatically assign events
      isTouchSupported: 'ontouchstart' in window.document,

      initSwipey: function() {
         //         alert('in initSwipey');
         //scroll the window up to hide the address bar of the browser.
         window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
         }, 100);

         /*mapping touch events to mouse events. Automatic registration of event
            based on the device. If touch enabled then touch event is registered.
            and if desktop browser then mouse event is registered.*/
         swipey.startEvent = swipey.isTouchSupported ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
         swipey.moveEvent = swipey.isTouchSupported ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
         swipey.endEvent = swipey.isTouchSupported ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup',

         //get all the instances of the HTML elements
         swipey.wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
         swipey.slideContainer = document.getElementById("sitePageContainer");
         //swipey.slides = slideContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");
         swipey.slides = document.getElementsByClassName("sitePage");

         //for iPhone, the width and height
         swipey.preferredWidth = window.innerWidth;
         //            alert("swipey.preferredWidth: " + swipey.preferredWidth);
         swipey.preferredHeight = window.innerHeight; //510 for android
         //            alert("swipey.preferredHeight: " + swipey.preferredHeight);
         //setting the width and height to our wrapper with overflow = hidden
         swipey.wrapper.style.width = swipey.preferredWidth + "px";
         //            alert("swipey.wrapper.style.width: " + swipey.wrapper.style.width);
         swipey.wrapper.style.height = swipey.preferredHeight + "px";
         //            alert("swipey.wrapper.style.height: " + swipey.wrapper.style.height);
         //setting the width to our <ul> element which holds all the <li> elements
         swipey.slideContainer.style.height = swipey.preferredHeight + "px";
         //            alert("swipey.slideContainer.style.height: " + swipey.slideContainer.style.height);
         swipey.slideContainer.style.width = swipey.slides.length *  swipey.preferredWidth + "px";
         //            alert("swipey.slideContainer.style.width: " + swipey.slideContainer.style.width);
         //display the <ul> container now
         swipey.slideContainer.style.display = "inline-block";
         //setting width and height for <li> elements - the slides
         for(var i=0;i<swipey.slides.length;i++)
         {
            swipey.slides[i].style.width = swipey.preferredWidth + "px";
            swipey.slides[i].style.height = swipey.preferredHeight + "px";
         }
         //calculating the max distance of travel for Slide Container i.e <ul> element
         swipey.maxDistance = swipey.slides.length * swipey.preferredHeight;
         //initialize and assign the touch events
         swipey.initEvents();
      },
      initEvents: function() {
         //registering touch events to the wrapper



         //$('#wrapper').bind(swipey.startEvent, swipey.startHandler );
         $('#wrapper').bind(swipey.startEvent, function(e){
            $('#wrapper').bind(swipey.moveEvent, swipey.moveHandler );
         } );

         $('#wrapper').bind(swipey.endEvent, swipey.endHandler );
      //swipey.wrapper.addEventListener(swipey.startEvent, swipey.startHandler, false);
      //swipey.wrapper.addEventListener(swipey.moveEvent, swipey.moveHandler, false);
      //swipey.wrapper.addEventListener(swipey.endEvent, swipey.endHandler, false);
      },
      //funciton called when touch start event is fired i.e finger is pressed on the screen
      startHandler: function(event) {
         //create appropriate event object to read the touch/mouse co-ordinates
         var eventObj = swipey.isTouchSupported ? event.touches[0] : event;

         //stores the starting X co-ordinate when finger touches the device screen
         swipey.startX = eventObj.pageX;
         //timer is set on
         swipey.timer = setInterval(function() {
            swipey.timerCounter++;
         }, 10);
         swipey.hasSwipeStarted = true;
         event.preventDefault(); //prevents the window from scrolling.
      },
      //funciton called when touch move event is fired i.e finger is dragged over the screen
      moveHandler: function(event) {
         if (swipey.hasSwipeStarted) {
            //create appropriate event object to read the touch/mouse co-ordinates
            var eventObj = swipey.isTouchSupported ? event.touches[0] : event;

            swipey.distanceX = eventObj.pageX - swipey.startX;
            //move the slide container along with the movement of the finger
            swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + (swipey.distanceX + swipey.currentDistance) + "px, 0,0)";
         }else{
            swipey.startHandler(event);
         }
      },
      //funciton called when touch end event is fired i.e finger is released from screen
      endHandler: function(event) {
         $('#wrapper').unbind(swipey.moveEvent, swipey.moveHandler );
         clearInterval(swipey.timer); //timer is stopped
         if(swipey.distanceX == 0) //if the intention is to tap on the image then open a link
         {
            var link_url = event.target.getAttribute("link"); //read the link from <img /> element
         //  window.open(link_url,"_blank");
         }
         else
         {
            if (swipey.distanceX > 0) {
               swipey.direction = "right";
            }
            if (swipey.distanceX < 0) {
               swipey.direction = "left";
            }
            //the following conditions have been discussed in details
            if ((swipey.direction == "right" && swipey.currentDistance == 0) || (swipey.direction == "left" && swipey.currentDistance == -(swipey.maxDistance - swipey.preferredWidth))) {
               swipey.comeBack();
            }
            else if (swipey.timerCounter < 30 && swipey.distanceX > 10) {
               swipey.moveRight();
            }
            else if (swipey.timerCounter < 30 && swipey.distanceX < -10) {
               swipey.moveLeft();
            }
            else if (swipey.distanceX <= -(swipey.preferredWidth / 2)) { //-160
               swipey.moveLeft();
            }
            else if (swipey.distanceX >= (swipey.preferredWidth / 2)) { //160
               swipey.moveRight();
            }
            else {
               swipey.comeBack();
            }
         }
         swipey.timerCounter = 0; //reset timerCounter
         swipey.hasSwipeStarted = false; //reset the boolean var
         swipey.distanceX = 0; //reset the distance moved for next iteration

         //alert(event.screenX+"::"+event.screenY);
         var element = document.elementFromPoint(event.screenX, event.screenY);
         var $element = $(element);

         alert($element.attr('id'));
         $("div.fixHeader").hide();
         $("#"+$element.attr('id')+" div.fixHeader").show();

      },
      moveLeft: function() {
         swipey.currentDistance += -swipey.preferredWidth;
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 300 + "ms";
         //using CSS3 transformations - translate3d function for movement
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + swipey.currentDistance + "px, 0,0)";
      },
      moveRight: function() {
         swipey.currentDistance += swipey.preferredWidth;
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 300 + "ms";
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + swipey.currentDistance + "px, 0,0)";
      },
      comeBack: function() {
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 250 + "ms";
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
         swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + swipey.currentDistance + "px, 0,0)";
      }
   }; //end of swipey object
   window.swipeyObj = swipey; //expose to global window object
})();

window.onload = function() {
   swipeyObj.initSwipey();
}  //invoke the init method to get started
```

**Updates:**

Below are structure, Now I am sliding sitePageContainer and sitePage appears on screen, now  I want to know which div is showing on screen (partypicturespage1 or partypicturespage2)

```
<div id="wrapper">
         <div id="sitePageContainer">
            <div class="sitePage" id="partypicturespage1"></div>
            <div class="sitePage" id="partypicturespage2"></div>
```

Comment: I added code Vishal, in endHandler I try to get it via position but still not work

Answer (score 4):

You can select your visible div the following way:

```
$("div.fixHeader:visible")
```

**Update:**

If all of your divs are visible then use a custom data-* attribute to keep track of the div that is currently in view. You can do it the following way:

```
$("div.fixHeader").attr('data-visible', true);
```

and select it the following way:

```
$("div.fixHeader[data-visible=true]");
```

and you remove the attribute so you don't select divs that are no longer in view:

```
$("div.fixHeader[data-visible=true]").attr('data-visible', false);
```

**Update #2:**

If you scroll the page by setting the container's left property, then determining which div is in view is done by the following calculation in pseudo code:

```
ceil(scrollContainer.left / divWidth) // if index starts from 1
floor(scrollContainer.left / divWidth) // if index starts from 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Konstantin, but all divs are in visible state, it just like changing their position so that it will not show on screen but they are still there...

Comment: @Ravi I edited with an explanation of how you can do this via a custom data-* attribute.

Comment: As you see in my code I calculate the swipe distance and move the upper most div towards left/right now all divs are having same property(if I give any custom attritute also), now my upper most div swipped by some distant and next div shown

Comment: @Ravi When your function shows a new div remove all data-visible attributes and apply true only to the current div.

Comment: thats my question, how would I know the current div as I am moving only the upper div(sitePageContainer) not the page div(class="sitePage"), see my html I updated above

Comment: @Ravi You can still calculate it. You know the width of the divs and if you don't you can get them with $('#divId').width(). You also know your left offset for your sitePageContainer. Just do the calculation.

Comment: I have each page of 320px and total pages are 5, so the sitePageContainer width is (320*5 = 1600px), now we move one page left and next page shows up, now I have all here but not the current div id whose width is 320px, sorry I might be little poor in this....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17054/discussion-between-ravi-and-konstantin-dinev)